# How to make crater like destruction in Box2d body

Tags: box2d

Can you please help me to do crater like effect in Box2d body, currently i am developing game with Cocos2d-x using box2d, please give me some suggestion for this

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Note:

- new fixtures must be convex
- new fixtures has limited count of points (by default, up to 8). As you can see in the picture, in new fixtures there are +1 points comparing to source fixture.
- in old box2d versions, you should sure right winding of the points
- it is not trivial task, to find bottom midle point. For example, I used [triangulation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) for this purposes.
- crater point can be projection of the contact point to nearest edge. Contact point itself can be somewhere near to edge.
- there is special case, when crater point is near to corner.